# error: Unable to fully sync the tree while cloning AOSP

Tags: android, git, android-source

Downloading android-8.1.0_r20. After downloading 45gb this error occurs.

Error message in the terminal:

```
error: libcore/: platform/libcore checkout ed54621bf38a761388fe5ea56d71c64befaa9f40 
error: Cannot checkout platform/libcore
Checking out: 100% (592/592), done in 15m55.329s
error: Unable to fully sync the tree.
error: Checking out local projects failed.
Failing repos:
external/libunwind
external/kmod
frameworks/compile/slang
external/autotest
libcore
Try re-running with "-j1 --fail-fast" to exit at the first error.
```

The source link of this git tag
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/tags/android-8.1.0_r20

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: This error does not seem to come from Git. Git is doing checkouts and something went wrong and some *other* system complained, overwriting (i.e., losing) any Git messages if there were any. As the error message itself says, try doing this again with `-j1 --fail-fast` so that any lower level error messages aren't destroyed.

Comment: The same happened today on my  PC as well. Tested on android-11.0.0_r45 and android-11.0.0_r48 failing repos: 'external/autotest, build/blueprint, external/elfutils, external/kmod, external/libunwind, frameworks/compile/slang, libcore`. Repos deleting and "-j1 --fail-fast" didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is probably due to the Partition type of your drive, where you are downloading the code.
Please make sure the drive Partition type is a Linux Filesystem (i.e. ext4).

Comment: Yes, formatting drive like ext4 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange but such issue happens when I try to sync AOSP on my Ubuntu PC to external usb-ssd drive but syncing to main drive to home directory works fine.

Moreover to reproduce such issue it is enough to clone one of the mentioned repos, e.g. `libcore`:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore -b android-11.0.0_r45
```

and then check it with `git status`,

on **main drive**:

```
$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

on **external usb-ssd drive**:

```
$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  deleted:    Android.bp
  deleted:    AndroidTest-core-tests.xml
  deleted:    CleanSpec.mk
  deleted:    JavaLibrary.bp
  deleted:    LICENSE
  deleted:    NOTICE
  ... 
  <6590 other deleted files>
  ...
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  Android.bp
  AndroidTest-core-tests.xml
  CleanSpec.mk
  JavaLibrary.bp
  LICENSE
  ...
  <total 34 untracked files>
  ...
  xml/
```

**Summary:**
If you use external drive for cloning AOSP try to do it into main drive (home directory).